# Como deixar uma <div> com o mesmo funcionamento de um radio button?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de métricas do funcionário, avaliação de desempenho, tenho `<div>`'s que foram colocadas em forma de tabela no meu formulário para qualificar cada opção como **Raro**, **As vezes**, **frequente**, **sempre** ou **N/A**.

A questão é que não sei se há possibilidade de fazer com que eu selecionando uma `<div>` da coluna *Raro*, por exemplo, e depois mudando a seleção para *Sempre* refizesse a seleção tirando a anterior. Lembrando que ao selecionar a `div` muda para a cor correspondente à coluna (esta funcionando mas está colorindo a tabela inteira por isso quero fazer como radio button, mas não sei fazer).

## Codigo PHP que gera o HTML:

```
<?php
$count = 1;
foreach($agrupadores as $agrupador){
    <div class="row" style='margin-bottom: 30px;'>
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="border:solid 1px #6495ED;padding:25px;">
        <b>$agrupador['mea_titulo']</b>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        foreach($alternativas[$agrupador['mea_codigo']] as $alternativa){
        <div class="col-xs-1">$alternativa['mat_titulo']</div>
    }
    </div>
        foreach($opcoes[$agrupador['mea_codigo']] as $opcao){ 
        <div class="row">
            <input type="hidden" name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="$opcao['mop_codigo']">
            <input type="hidden" name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="">
            <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q$count></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">$opcao['mop_titulo']</div>
            foreach($alternativas[$agrupador['mea_codigo']] as $alternativa){
            <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="$alternativa['mat_cor']" data-opcao="$opcao['mop_codigo']" data-alternativa="$alternativa['mat_codigo']" data-valor="$alternativa['mat_valor']" data-agrupador="$agrupador['mea_codigo']">&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="alternativa" id="alternativa" class="alternativa" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
        }
        </div>
            $count++; }
    </div>    
        </div>    
}
?>
```

## HTML gerado

```js
$('body').on("click", "#heColunas", function() {

  var alternativa = $(this).data("alternativa"); // retorna o código da alternativa da coluna selecionada
  var valor = $(this).data("valor"); // retorna o valor da coluna selecionada  
  var agrupador = $(this).data("agrupador"); // retorna o código do agrupador vinculado à alternativa
  var opcao = $(this).data("opcao"); // retorna o código da opção vinculada à alternativa
  var cor_alt = $(this).data("cor"); // retorna a cor da alternativa


  if (valor == "2") {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#" + cor_alt);
  } else if (valor == "3") {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#" + cor_alt);
  } else if (valor == "4") {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#" + cor_alt);
  } else {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#" + cor_alt);
  }
});
```

```css
.dv_border {
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}

.heColunas {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12" id="div_perguntas" style="margin-top:70px;">
  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="border:solid 1px #6495ED;padding:25px;">
      <b>COMPORTAMENTAL</b>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">Raro</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">Às Vezes</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">Frequente</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">Sempre</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">NA</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="501-1" type="hidden">
        <input name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">Executa a carga horária proposta, correspondente a sua função, levando em consideração o horário de entrada, almoço e saída.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ff0000" data-opcao="501-1" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-1" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-1" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-1" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff" data-opcao="501-1" data-alternativa="501-5" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="501-2" type="hidden">
        <input name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">Possui faltas no período.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ff0000" data-opcao="501-2" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-2" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-2" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-2" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff" data-opcao="501-2" data-alternativa="501-5" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="501-3" type="hidden">
        <input name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q3</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">Se possui faltas, todas são justificadas.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ff0000" data-opcao="501-3" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-3" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-3" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-3" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff" data-opcao="501-3" data-alternativa="501-5" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="501-4" type="hidden">
        <input name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q4</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">É flexível, sabendo se adaptar a todas mudanças que ocorrem.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ff0000" data-opcao="501-4" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-4" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-4" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-4" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff" data-opcao="501-4" data-alternativa="501-5" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="501-5" type="hidden">
        <input name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q5</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">Está sempre disposto a realizar as atividades propostas pelo cliente, pela coordenação ou pela empresa.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ff0000" data-opcao="501-5" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-5" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-5" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-5" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff" data-opcao="501-5" data-alternativa="501-5" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="501-6" type="hidden">
        <input name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">É receptivo aos feedbacks recebidos.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ff0000" data-opcao="501-6" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-6" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-6" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-6" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff" data-opcao="501-6" data-alternativa="501-5" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="501-7" type="hidden">
        <input name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q7</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">Possui boa Relação com seus colegas de trabalho, subordinados, superiores e cliente.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ff0000" data-opcao="501-7" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-7" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-7" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-7" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff" data-opcao="501-7" data-alternativa="501-5" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="501-8" type="hidden">
        <input name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q8</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">Mantém uma postura calma diante a situações adversas.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ff0000" data-opcao="501-8" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-8" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-8" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-8" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff" data-opcao="501-8" data-alternativa="501-5" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="501-9" type="hidden">
        <input name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q9</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">Participa dos eventos sugeridos pela empresa e estimula a sua equipe a participar.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ff0000" data-opcao="501-9" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-9" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-9" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-9" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff" data-opcao="501-9" data-alternativa="501-5" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="501-10" type="hidden">
        <input name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q10</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">Segue as normas da empresa e faz com que seus subordinados as sigam também.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ff0000" data-opcao="501-10" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-10" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-10" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-10" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff" data-opcao="501-10" data-alternativa="501-5" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="501-11" type="hidden">
        <input name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q11</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">É organizado, mantendo a mesa, diretório e pasta física do projeto dentro dos padrões.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ff0000" data-opcao="501-11" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-11" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-11" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-11" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff" data-opcao="501-11" data-alternativa="501-5" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="501-12" type="hidden">
        <input name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q12</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">Se preocupa em melhorar e se desenvolver cada vez mais.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ff0000" data-opcao="501-12" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-12" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-12" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-12" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff" data-opcao="501-12" data-alternativa="501-5" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="mop_codigo" id="mop_codigo" value="501-13" type="hidden">
        <input name="mat_codigo" id="mat_codigo" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas">Q13</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 dv_border heColunas">Evita desperdícios e a elevação de custos, tanto para a empresa, quanto para o cliente.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ff0000" data-opcao="501-13" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-13" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-13" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-13" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff" data-opcao="501-13" data-alternativa="501-5" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Não tem como incorporar dentro da `div` um `radio` e usufruir de seu funcionamento natural?

Comment: assim mesmo que fica, só que nao sei como fazer para só colorir a que eu selecionar =(

Comment: O que pretendia fazer: que as divs da linha funcionassem como radio buttons ou seja cliquei em uma colore aquela com sua respectiva cor como visto no código e se for clicar em outra da mesma linha para modificar a resposta de sempre para as vezes por exemplo descolorisse a que estava selecionada e colorir a nova selecionada como radio button entende.

Answer (score 4):

Neste exemplo estou usando bootstrap só pra embelezar

```js
$(function() {
  $('div.product-chooser').not('.disabled').find('div.product-chooser-item').find('span').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('span').removeClass('label-danger');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('div.product-chooser-item').find('span').addClass('label-info');
    $(this).addClass('label-danger');
    $(this).parent().find('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true);
  });
});
$('#button').on('click', function(e) {
  alert($('input[type="radio"]:checked').val());
})
```

```css
div.product-chooser div.product-chooser-item input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 product-chooser">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2 product-chooser-item">
    <span class="label label-info">Raro</span>
    <input name="box" value="raro" required type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2 product-chooser-item">
    <span class="label label-info">As vezes</span>
    <input name="box" value="asvezes" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2 product-chooser-item">
    <span class="label label-info">Frequente</span>
    <input name="box" value="frequente" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2 product-chooser-item">
    <span class="label label-info">Sempre</span>

    <input name="box" value="sempre" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2 product-chooser-item">
    <span class="label label-info">N/A</span>
    <input name="box" value="na" type="radio">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 form-horizontal" style="margin-top:30px;">
  <button name="button" id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Prosseguir</button>
</div>
```

Veja que de qualquer jeito uso um input tipo radio, porem eu oculto ele do formulário

---

## Com esse HTML que você passou:

```js
$(function() {
  $('td').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true);
    $(this).parent().find('td').css("background-color", "#fff");
    color = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').val();
    color = pintar(color);
    $(this).css("background-color", color);
  });
});

function pintar(cor) {
  switch (cor) {
    case 'raro':
      return '#f00';
      break;
    case 'asvezes':
      return '#fc0';
      break;
    case 'frequentemente':
      return '#9c0';
      break;
    case 'sempre':
      return '#090';
      break;
    case 'na':
      return 'fff';
      break;
    default:
      return '';
  }
}
$('#enviar').on('click', function(e) {
  var teste = $('input[type=radio]:checked').map(
    function() {
      return {
        "name": this.name,
        "value": this.value
      }
    }).get();
    console.log(teste);
})
```

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-yw4l {
  vertical-align: top
}

tr input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

"ff0000" data-opcao="501-5" data-alternativa="501-1" data-valor="2" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;
</div><div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffcc00" data-opcao="501-5" data-alternativa="501-2" data-valor="3" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;
</div><div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="99cc00" data-opcao="501-5" data-alternativa="501-3" data-valor="4" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;
</div><div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="009900" data-opcao="501-5" data-alternativa="501-4" data-valor="5" data-agrupador="501-1">&nbsp;
</div><div class="col-xs-1 dv_border heColunas" id="heColunas" data-cor="ffffff"
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l" colspan="7">PESQUISA COMPORTAMENTAL</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Raro</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">As vezes</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Frequentemente</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Sempre</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Q1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Executa a carga horária proposta, correspondente a sua função, levando em consideração o horário de entrada, almoço e saída.</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input name="q1" value="raro" required type="radio"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input name="q1" value="asvezes" type="radio"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input name="q1" value="frequentemente" type="radio"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input name="q1" value="sempre" type="radio"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input name="q1" value="na" type="radio"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Q2</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Possui faltas no período.</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input name="q2" value="raro" required type="radio"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input name="q2" value="asvezes" type="radio"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input name="q2" value="frequentemente" type="radio"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input name="q2" value="sempre" type="radio"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input name="q2" value="na" type="radio"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="enviar" name="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

A função que verifica cada questão selecionada eu implementei usando o `map` do `jQuery`, veja:

```
$('#enviar').on('click', function(e) {
  var teste = $('input[type=radio]:checked').map(
    function() {
      return {
        "name": this.name,
        "value": this.value
      }
    }).get();
    console.log(teste);
})
```

Ela busca cada radio que esta selecionado e monta o array com o nome do radio group (no caso o nome da questão) e o valor que esta selecionado

```
jQuery(function() {
  // Em qualquer td que ser clicado 
  jQuery('td').on('click', function() {
    // Procura o radio dentro do td clicado e seleciona ele, desconsiderando os outros do grupo da questão
    jQuery(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true);
    // Procura o no pai do td, no caso tr, e seta todos os td's dessa seleção com a cor padrão #fff
    jQuery(this).parent().find('td').css("background-color", "#fff");
    // pega o valor do td
    color = jQuery(this).find('input[type="radio"]').val();
    // de acordo com o valor selecionado eu obtenho também a cor
    color = pintar(color);
    // pinto o td clicado
    jQuery(this).css("background-color", color);
  });
});
```

Comment: Bah carinha valeu pela ajuda ja estou entendendo melhor como devo resolver vou fazer alguns testes aqui no sistema e volto a falar se deu certo ou não, mas ja adianto valeu mesmo todos pela ajuda! Grato!

Comment: obrigado pela atenção, mas não to conseguindo especifiquei o input como visibility hidden dentro da div e no jquery só pus pra modificar com a cor referente aquela alternativa como foi inserida no banco de dados mas esta selecionando todas as divs e colorindo tudo kkkk. tem como me ajudar mais um pouco estou disponibilizando o código agora.

Comment: @LucasPereira sugiro que remova os comentários que não são mais necessários, veja: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5853/14262